# Adding a ApplicationBarIconButton from Application.Resources in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a ApplicationBarIconButton which I use repeatedly on multiple pages.

I want to be able to define the Click action in my Application C# file.

I have

```
<Application.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
        x:Key="AddLocationAppBarIconBut"
        IconUri="/icons/appbar.add.rest.png"
        Text="location"
        Click="Add_Location_Event" />
```

in my App.xaml file and I want to load it into another page I have under

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

How do I go about this exactly?
Can I bind a click event to an event in my Application cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't!

In full WPF framework, you'd be able to do something like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
   <shell:ApplicationBar>
       <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
           <StaticResource ResourceKey="AddLocationAppBarIconBut" />
       </shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
   </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

The trick here is in the usage of [StaticResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189045%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but Silverlight doesn't have a backing class representation like that; you can only use the Markup Extension as `{StaticResource AddLocationAppBarIconBut}`, but this won't help you here!

What you can is define the full ApplicationBar object as a resource and then just call it on the page like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ApplicationBar="{StaticResource ApplicationBarResource}">

    <!-- remaining code -->

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage />
```